# add image as background to text d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am using this example: http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033.
I want to add image before each node text and also have different font-style to each node.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it but this may work:

```
 nodeEnter.append("svg:image")
     .attr('width', 20)
     .attr('height', 20)
     .attr("xlink:href","img/myimage.png");
```

Add it to the 'update' function, once nodeEnter is created.

Comment: Thanks for the response..
I want this image at the starting of the text.

Comment: Please try to do it yourself, then if you have any question ask it here. StackOverflow is a place to help not to do free work.